# clustering problem

Tags: cluster-analysis

hi every body can any one tell me how to connect two computer which is not runnin the same os  means how to connect a computer which running linux to a computer which is running windows ,or more technically how to make a  hitrogenous cluster or cluster with diffrent hardware or different operating Systems. if any body know any thing about it please tell me i 'll be thankfull to you for this .

Comment: What sort of cluster are you going for? If it is for a specific application that you are writing then you might be able to do your clustering at the application level (and keep the OS out of it) by having a control server break up the work into work units and distribute them to the clients (this is how many public grid projects such as Folding@Home and Seti@Home do their clustering).

Answer (score 0):

Two fundamental requirements here:

1. Some platform-independent communication mechanism
2. The ability to create the processing logic on each platform

There's a long history of folks devising communication mechanisms, proprietory and open. These days Web Services are so widely available I would start with them.

For implementation, it's clearly possible to write an implementation on each platform, in whatever language feels best on that platform, C# here, C++ there. But that's really making life hard, so it's by far best to write portable implementations. That's technically possible in many languages, C, PHP, Ruby etc.

My current skill-set is Java, so I'd be using that. Java web Service frameworks are pretty solid so that would get the job done.